# File handlers and file objects

Tags: python

You have to know a bit of background even before asking an intelligent question, so please excuse me if parts of this question are hard to understand (it is likely worded imperfectly).

I find these file handler (or maybe file objects) weird. For example, I feel like it's a common feature in some libraries to have something like

`data = library.read('local_file.extension')`

and then you have to pipe the data into an actual readable format

`dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data)`

the original object named `data` seems kind of pointless (I believe sometimes called a file object--never seems to really be used on its own).

I also don't understand the whole syntax of file handlers

e.g.
`with open(filepath, 'r') as filehandler: data_strcuture = pickle.load(filepath)`

it feels weirdly convoluted compared to something like
`df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`

Everything seems to work out fine, but it feels roundabout (like there's a weird extra step) and I'm wondering if I'm missing anything. So I guess the question is: Is there a reason for either of these design choices, or is it just legacy?

Thanks for your patience

This is not so much a bug, but rather a question about design.

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? `pd.read_csv(...)` is a facade method that loads csv with some other things that user may or may not care about. Stricting user to using only such methods makes the library less flexible

Comment: Instead of usual file objects, so called file-like objects can be used in many places. These can read from or write to compressed files, data in memory, remote files over a network connection or other resources. The abstraction helps to cover all such cases at once.

Comment: This is too vague for a definitive answer, but it's also a good sort of question to ask, so I'll give you a sort of handwavy answer, which is that it's about modularity; you don't want to make it so that you can *only* create a DataFrame out of a physical file on disk, because sometimes you might want to store that data somewhere else.  A really easy example would be testing, where you typically want to avoid creating actual files if you can avoid it.

Comment: Another concrete example might be, if I want to write a script that extracts information from a binary file (PDF for example), and that PDF is hosted on a URL, and I don't want to have to download- and save that PDF as a file on my filesystem, my script can make a request to that resource, save the response bytes in a file-like BytesIO object, and then open- and parse that file-like object using a third-party PDF parsing library of my choice. The filesystem is not involved.